# TFSBuild call in Powershell throwing error

Tags: powershell

I get the following error in `powershell ISE`:

> tfsbuild : The term 'tfsbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

I have tried the full path of tfsbuild, but then I still get an error.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tfsbuild start /collection:"http://xxxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"  /builddefinition:"yyyy/zzzz"`

Comment: is the answer to this to add the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"  folder to the environment path?  i thought maybe there would be a way that include adding a module, or something to powershell.  i'd rather not have to set the environment path globally just to run this script.  i essentially tried to figure out what is going on in the VsDevCmd.bat file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools"

Comment: Is the path enclosed in spaces? Are you running it using `& "C:\Program Files ..."` (& is important when there are spaces)? Posting the code would help provide an answer. The error you gave points to there something being wrong with how you specified the path - "tfsbuild" is somehow separate from the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If TfsBuild.exe is not in your PATH then you need to:

- Enclose full path in quotes
- Prefix call with &
- Include extension .exe

`& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TfsBuild.exe" start...`

Alternatively you can change your working directory to the folder containing the .exe and simply 'dot source' the executable.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"
.\TfsBuild.exe start...
```